# SelectedItem issue in WPF ListBoxItem MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am new to WPF and attempting to design following the MVVM design pattern.  My issue is I cannot get the selected Item when the user selects this item in the ListBox.  I appreciate your help, Thanks.  I have stripped out some of the code in the methods that is not needed.

Sorry I should add the listbox named: lbPositionAttributeMasters is the one that is not working.

XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel />
    <ListBox x:Name="lbPositionAttributeMasters" ItemsSource="{Binding PositionAttributeMasterCollection}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAttributeMaster, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="0,10,280,10">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding PositionAttributeMasterDescription}"></TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>

    <ListBox x:Name="lbPositionAttributesForMaster" ItemsSource="{Binding PositionAttributesCollection}" Margin="270,10,10,10">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding PositionAttributeDescription}"></TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>

</Grid>
```

ViewModel:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private ObservableCollection<PositionAttributes> _positionAttributeMasterCollection;
    private ObservableCollection<PositionAttributes> _positionAttributeCollection;
    private IList<PositionAttributes> _positionAttributeMasterDescription;
    private IList<PositionAttributes> _positionAttributeDescription;
    private PositionAttributes _selectedAttributeMaster;
    public PositionAttributesViewModel()
    {

    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<PositionAttributes> PositionAttributeMasterCollection
    {
        get { return _positionAttributeMasterCollection;}
        set
        {
            _positionAttributeMasterCollection = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("PositionAttributeMasterCollection");
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<PositionAttributes> PositionAttributeCollection
    {
        get { return _positionAttributeCollection; }
        set
        {
            _positionAttributeCollection = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("PositionAttributeCollection");
        }
    }

    public IList<PositionAttributes> PositionAttributeMasterDescription
    {
        get { return _positionAttributeMasterDescription; }
        set
        {
            _positionAttributeMasterDescription = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("PositionAttributeMasterDescription");
        }
    }

    public PositionAttributes SelectedAttributeMaster
    {
        get{ return _selectedAttributeMaster; }

        set
        {
            _selectedAttributeMaster = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedAttributeMaster");
        }

    }

    public IList<PositionAttributes> PositionAttributeDescription
    {
        get { return _positionAttributeDescription; }
        set
        {
            _positionAttributeDescription = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("PositionAttributeDescription");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets all Attribute Masters and Sub Attribute Masters
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public ObservableCollection<PositionAttributes> GetPositionAttributeMasters()
    {

        foreach(var item in listofpositionAttributes)//Add to observable collection
        {
            PositionAttributeMasterCollection.Add(item);
        }

        return PositionAttributeMasterCollection;
    }


            foreach (var item in positionAttributesInMaster)//Add to observable collection
            {
                PositionAttributeCollection.Add(item);
            }
        }

        return PositionAttributeCollection;
    }

}
```

Comment: The `lbPositionAttributeMasters` list box does not work?  In the case of `lbPositionAttributesForMaster` the selected item is not bound to anything.  The items source binding does work, though?

Comment: @JasonBoyd Yes sorry its the lbPositionAttributeMasters that does not work

Comment: Are you seeing any activity of the selected item property setter when you change the selection? Put a breakpoint there and see if it is getting set. Your code looks right for MVVM relying on bindings rather than events so wonder if your binding is incorrectly defined.

Comment: To build on @kidshaw 's comment, I created a test project, inserted your code, and the property bound to SelectedItem changes as I select items in the list. So, can you describe exactly what you're expecting and what's not working?

Comment: @kidshaw the SelectedAttributeMaster property is hit when I select an item in the ListView however, I need to retrieve the Item selected.  Currently the _selectedAttributeMaster value is being set to: {ClientRatesWPF.Model.PositionAttributes}

Comment: Looks as though you have the answer. If you wanted a specific attribute of the class, you can look into binding the selected value and value path properties another day

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you provided is working as expected. What you describe in the comments, is that during debugging you see `{ClientRatesWPF.Model.PositionAttributes}` as a value being set to `SelectedAttributeMaster`.
This is completely correct, because the debugger doesn't know how to show you anything more meaningfull. You can do two things:

1) Apply the [`DebuggerDisplay`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228992(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute to your class:

```
[DebuggerDisplay("Description = {PositionAttributeMasterDescription}")]
public class PositionAttributes
{        
    public string PositionAttributeMasterDescription { get; set; }
}
```

2) Use the Visual Studio debugger to show you additional information:
[image: Screenshot Visual Studio while break on property setter]

Answer (score 0):

Step 1.
Add a relay command in your viewmodel

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Command which is fired when a list view item is selected in   the    main window 
    /// </summary>
    public RelayCommand SelectionChangedCmd { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The listview item selected from the collection.
    /// </summary>
    public Feature SelectedAttributedMaster  { get; set; }
```

In the constructor of your viewmodel:

```
      public PositionAttributesViewModel()
      {
        PositionAttributeMasterCollection = new    
                ObservableCollection<PositionAttributes >();

        SelectionChangedCmd = new RelayCommand(() =>        
              PositionAttributesSelectionChanged(), () => true);


     }


 //implement what you want to do on selection 
  private void PositionAttributesSelectionChanged()
  {
      if(PositionAttributeMasterCollection !=null &&     
       SelectedAttributedMaster !=null)
        {
           PositionAttributes feature = SelectedAttributedMaster  as     
           PositionAttributes 
           //Update the window whenever we select a new feature.
           Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.DynamicInvoke(delegate()
           {
                //further implementation

           });

        }
  }
```

In your XAML add the references and rest of the code.

```
   <Window x:Class="Something.MainWindow" 
        xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;  assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
        xmlns:cmd="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.WPF4">

  <ListBox x:Name="lbPositionAttributeMasters" ItemsSource="{Binding PositionAttributeMasterCollection}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAttributeMaster}" Margin="0,10,280,10">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding PositionAttributeMasterDescription}"></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectionChangedCmd}"
                         CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
                    </i:EventTrigger>
       </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Thanks but this seems quite complex, I thought the SelectedItem Property binding should work?

Comment: @David, MVVM light is a great framework, it takes very little time to understand, the relay commands (event to commands) make life easy.